# Object detection very low accuracy

Tags: python, image-processing, keras

- I am trying to make **cifar-10** object detection. However, all I can get is `%20` accuracy..
- I don't use any preprocessing though but still isn't `%20` is too low? Also I use `Canny Edge Detector` and saved those edges to some folder.
- When I use that edge images of Canny output instead of Gray Scale normal images, accuracy gets drop down to `%15`...
- I believe while using the output of the Canny I should get a higher accuracy, not lower.
  Here is how I create data generator:

```py
    train= pd.read_csv("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/trainLabels.csv")
    for i in range(len(train.index)):
        train.iloc[i,0] = str( train.iloc[i,0])+".png"
    #    print(train.iloc[i,0]
    # Create a train data with Data Generator
    train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=45, rescale=1./255, horizontal_flip=True)
    train_data = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe= train, directory = ("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/train/edges"), x_col="id" , y_col="label",seed = 42,
    batch_size = 64, shuffle = True, class_mode="categorical",target_size = (32, 32), color_mode="grayscale")
    #Create a Verify data with Data Generator
    verify_data = train_gen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe= train, directory = ("C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/train/edges"), x_col="id" , y_col="label",seed = 42,
    batch_size = 64, shuffle = True, class_mode="categorical",target_size = (32, 32), color_mode="grayscale")
```

In here when you look at the folder path:`"C:/Users/yazilim1/Desktop/Jupyter/cifar-10/train/edges"`, I am using edges of the images.
I change the input from there from normal images to edges.And of course when I use edges I don't use `color_mode="grayscale"`.

Here is the model:

```py
    #Create Model
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape=(32,32,1) ))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3)))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Conv2D(128,(3,3)))
    model.add(Activation("relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(1))
    model.add(Dense(10,Activation("softmax")))
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer="adam", metrics =['accuracy'])
    #Model fit
    STEP_SIZE_TRAIN=train_data.n // train_data.batch_size
    STEP_SIZE_VALID= verify_data.n // verify_data.batch_size
    model.fit(train_data,
                        steps_per_epoch=STEP_SIZE_TRAIN,
                        validation_data=verify_data,
                        validation_steps=STEP_SIZE_VALID,
                        epochs=2,
                        verbose=1
                       )
    score = model.evaluate(verify_data)
    print('Test loss:', score[0])
    print('Test accuracy:', score[1])
```

And here is how edges and grayscale images look like for an additional information:

[image: Grayscale & edge images]

- So why the accuracy is that low? And how can I increase it.
- I don't know additional way rather than using **grayscale images** and **Canny edge detector**.

Comment: CIFAR10 is not an object detection dataset, you are doing image classification

Comment: Yet somethow it detects objects doesn't it?^^

Comment: No, don't be naive, object detection is a task in computer vision that is well defined, you classify multiple objects and output bounding boxes, so what you are doing is not object detection.

Comment: Ah and that is a good reason to downvote a question. Also this question is not opinion based. There might be multiple reasons and there is a code that needs to be improved. It is not a question like which algorithm is better.

Comment: Also do not assume to know who made downvotes.

Comment: Well that was a general addition, was not for you :)

Comment: Note that your question is off-topic, according to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/404075/how-should-we-handle-machine-learning-questions-asking-for-performance-improveme

Comment: Thank you for the information. On the other hand, according to accepted answer that is a "leave it as it is" question. Not an off topic question.

Comment: No, none of those cases apply to you, nobody can give you a clear reason why it does not work, other than the model is too simple (have you researched models used for CIFAR10?), which is not a programming problem. Do not forget that Stack Overflow is only meant for programming issues, not machine learning ones.

Comment: Thanks again, as Frightera mentioned it was caused by the usage of 2 flatten().When I reduce it to 1, accuracy increased to %40 with 2 epoch.

Comment: And when the num. of epochs will be increased I believe the accuracy also will be increased. I did not accept the answer yet though. Since I don't want to open a new question for "why using edges as input decreases the acc." and I am waiting for an answer for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CIFAR-10 is a difficult dataset to generalize with 90%+ accuracy. You can try:

- More complex network
- Flattening 1 time ( I see you did it two times, that might affect.)
- Using more augmentation options like zooming etc.
- Using callbacks such as ReduceLROnPlateau
- While making the network complex, you should use regularization to avoid overfitting.

After flattening you can use Dense layers like this, you didn't pass any activations to your dense layers at the end:

```
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(256, activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(128, activation = tf.nn.relu))
model.add(Dense(10,Activation("softmax")))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, so what might be the reason that using gray scale images give better results than using outputs of the Canny Edge Detector?

Comment: I am not sure but with Canny Detector you might be losing information, for example the car's tires seem missing. Also images' sizes may not be eligible for this (32x32x1)